# Siddhi partition by request time stamp

Tags: siddhi

How do you partition a request by timestamp?

## The first minute goes to the first stream and then the rest goes to a second stream for three hours. Then after The three hours, the first minute goes the first stream and the rest go the second stream.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On a high level we can do something like this:

1. We would need a Siddhi table, where we *store* a pivot timestamp. We can route events to streams based on this pivot timestamp. Let's call this table: `TimeStampTable(pivotTimestamp long)`.
2. At each event of `IncomingStream(eventTimestamp long, ..otherAttributes..)`, we do a join with `TimeStampTable`, and check if an entry exists at `TimeStampTable`.

   - A. If an entry doesn't exist, insert `eventTimestamp` to `TimeStampTable`. This is going to function as the pivot timestamp. Get `0` as `timeDiff`.
   - B. If exists, get `eventTimestamp - pivotTimestamp` as `timeDiff`.
3. Based on `timeDiff`, put a label to each event (basically add a string attribute and pass it to the next stream). I.e, `WITHIN_FIRST_MINUTE`, and `WITHIN_THREE_HOURS`.
4. Route events to appropriate streams based on the above label.
5. At step (2.B), if `timeDiff >= 3 hours`, replace `pivotTimestamp` with the current timestamp.